# try multi catch vs try catch by if

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, try-catch, efficientnet

What are the implications of using a single catch block with type checking versus multiple catch blocks for different exception types in C#?

In C#, when handling exceptions, one can use a single catch block with type checking:

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is ObjectNotFoundException)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
    }

    else if (ex is ModelValidationException)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, ex);
    }

    //... another type of exception 

    else {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, one can use separate catch blocks for each exception type:

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (ObjectNotFoundException ex)
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
}
catch (ModelValidationException ex)
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, ex);
}

//... another type of exception

catch (Exception ex)
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
}
```

What are the advantages and potential pitfalls of each approach? Are there any performance considerations or best practices to consider?

Comment: the latter, although, your examples differ.

Comment: "which is better in performance" well test and find out. As for practice, the latter is better but best practice questions are off-topic on Satck Overflow.

Comment: Without seeing how the first continues, the obvious worry is that any exceptions you don't recognise might end up being *silently ignored*. Believe it or not it's *usually* better for unhandled error conditions to loudly crash the process, which the second will do by default.

Comment: Neither of these methods affects code readability. I just want to know, from a hardware and system resource usage perspective, which of these methods works better and more efficiently.

Comment: Consider that all types of exceptions are considered in both solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second approach is better since you don't want to swallow all other exceptions silently. But instead of letting the process to crash after getting uncaught exception types, it would be better to catch them, log error details and return an internal server error:

```
try
{
   // ...
}
catch (ObjectNotFoundException ex)
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
}
catch (ModelValidationException ex)
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, ex);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // log this error, so you are notified about it
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is correct, catch specific exception types.

The first approach,

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is ObjectNotFoundException)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
    }

    if (ex is ModelValidationException)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, ex);
    }
}
```

**is a bad idea**, do not do this! It suppresses and discards unexpected exceptions.

You don't rethrow the exception if it doesn't match one of your if conditions. You could radically improve things by doing,

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ...
    throw;
}
```

However, if you want a catch block that catches specific types, use the conventional pattern. This is more likely to be understood and supported in the future and less likely to lead to unexpected bugs.

---

Additionally, I suspect the typed catches would have performance advantages as the built in type checking is likely optimized.

However, you would need to run benchmarks with a defined workload to validate that assumption.